# can not click on link which is created in php storm

Tags: html, phpstorm, php

Hi I know it will be maybe an obvious error but I cannot find. 
I am working on a website and I am also a beginner. I have link which is an about us link which is not opening the warning says :

The requested resource /about-us.phtml was not found on this server.

Thank you for the help if more information or code is needed please tell me

Comment: It does not recognize it. See if you use some framework like codeigniter and you give alias to model then it will have issues finding files OR folder structure is wrong , file is not exist.

Comment: can I send the file and you can have a look i am using wamp as a server local. i am using bootstrap is a simple link which should work

Comment: how can i send it over- your email?>?

Comment: Goto my profile page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3326275/jquery-php-magento-com?tab=profile

Comment: i mean i send an email please check

Comment: Its sent , Not send as its past tense.

Comment: can you please confirm if you received it ?

Comment: So in which file u got error?

Comment: it is the menu when you click on about-us it is not working and i get this error The requested resource /about-us.phtml was not found on this server. even any other link